React (TypeScript) - Unable to Use Process Environment
I am working on building my first React application (using TypeScript), however I am running into an issue building the application while trying to use environment variables.  My folder structure is:
ls-app
  \src
    \environments
    \libs
    .env.development
    .env.production
  webpack.config.js

I have tried to define a plugin to support the use of environment variables, however I always end up with the following error message:
PS C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app> npm run build

> lw-app@1.0.0 build
> webpack --mode production

C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:4706
                        if (buildInfo.assets) {
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')
    at Compilation.createModuleAssets (C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilatio    at Compilation.createModuleAssets (C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:4706:18)
    at C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3196:13
    at Compilation._runCodeGenerationJobs (C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compil    at C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3196:13
    at Compilation._runCodeGenerationJobs (C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compil    at Compilation._runCodeGenerationJobs (C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3351:11)
    at C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3181:12
    at C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3443:6
    at C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
    at done (C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3522:9)
    at C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3404:8
    at C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3521:5
    at C:\..\..\..\Programming\LW\src\LW-fe\lw-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:97:5

Node.js v20.16.0

My basic webpack.config.js is as follows (with the plugin defined):
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const DotEnvPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');

dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
    modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin(),
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};

and this will build/run fine.  However, if I try adding any of the following to the plugins array, I get the error provided above:
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)
})

new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': 'process.env',
})

new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': JSON.stringify('test')
})

new DotEnvPlugin({
  path: './src/.env.development'
})

I also tried commenting out the dotenv.config() statement, but it made no difference.  The only report of the same exact error was in [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')][1], but there was no solution provided.  For reference, here are the packages installed:
├── @auth0/auth0-react@2.2.4
├── @babel/core@7.25.2
├── @babel/preset-env@7.25.4
├── @babel/preset-react@7.24.7
├── @babel/preset-typescript@7.24.7
├── @emotion/react@11.13.3
├── @emotion/styled@11.13.0
├── @mui/material@6.0.1
├── @types/react-dom@18.3.0
├── @types/react@18.3.4
├── babel-loader@9.1.3
├── css-loader@7.1.2
├── dotenv-webpack@8.1.0
├── dotenv@16.4.5
├── html-webpack-plugin@5.6.0
├── i18next@23.14.0
├── react-dom@18.3.1
├── react-i18next@15.0.1
├── react-router-dom@6.26.1
├── react@18.3.1
├── sass-loader@16.0.1
├── sass@1.77.8
├── style-loader@4.0.0
├── tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin@4.1.0
├── tsconfig-paths@4.2.0
├── typescript@5.5.4
├── webpack-cli@5.1.4
├── webpack-dev-server@5.0.4
└── webpack@5.94.0

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated as I am really lost on where to go from here, especially with this being my first React project.  TIA.
UPDATE #1
I made a modification so that I can read the variables in my .env.development file, by doing the following:
module.exports = () => {
  const env = dotenv.config({path: './src/.env.development'});.parsed.
  console.log(env);

  ...
  ...
}

With the console.log statement, I see the four variables I defined written to the console, so I know that dotenv is correctly loading the values.  However, even updating one of the plugin definitions to:
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.config({path: './src/.env.development'}).parsed)
})

still results in the asset error message.
UPDATED #2
So part of the problem seems that I was defining the plugin in the plugins array under resolve instead of the root one.  My updated webpack.config.js file is:
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');

module.exports = () => {

  const env = dotenv.config({ path: './src/.env.development' }).parsed;
  console.log(env);

  return {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
      modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
      plugins: [
        new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
        new TsconfigPathsPlugin(),
      ]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        TEST_VAL: JSON.stringify("TEST_VAL")
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html'
      }),
    ]
  }
};

If I try to build with this, I still get the same asset error.  However, if I remove the HtmlWebpackPlugin plugin from the array, then I get a different error:
assets by status 0 bytes [cached] 1 asset

ERROR in Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

webpack 5.94.0 compiled with 1 error in 197 ms

UPDATED #3
Now I am really lost because if I only leave HtmlWebpackPlugin in the plugin array, I am now getting the asset error, even though it was working with only this before.  If I remove it, and simply leave the plugins array empty, then I am getting the path error I provided in Updated #2.
[1]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')

Have you tried using EnvironmentPlugin?

If I try putting new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV']) into the plugins array, I still get the same error.  I have also updated the original post with some additional information on changes I made and confirms that I am indeed loading the environment variables I defined.
